# Conditionally import a playbook based on vars_prompt in Ansible

Tags: ansible, devops

I am using the following ansible script to import a playbook based on the user input,

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "cleanup"
      prompt: "Do you want to run cleanup? Enter [yes/no]"
      private: no

- name: run the cleanup yaml file
  import_playbook: cleanup.yml
  when: cleanup == "yes"
```

Execution log:

```
bash-$ ansible-playbook -i hosts cleanup.yml

Do you want to run cleanup? Enter [yes/no]: no

PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

PLAY [master] ********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.56.128]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'cleanup == \"yes\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (cleanup == \"yes\"): 'cleanup' is undefined"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/admin/playbook/cleanup.retry

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
192.168.56.128             : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

It throws error in the imported playbook not in the mail playbook.
Please help me to import a playbook based on user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vars_prompt` variables are only defined in the play in which they were called. In order to use them in other plays, a workaround is to use `set_fact` to bind the variable to a host, then use `hostvars` to access that value from the second play.

For instance:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "cleanup"
      prompt: "Do you want to run cleanup? Enter [yes/no]"
      private: no
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
          cleanup: "{{cleanup}}"
    - debug:
          msg: 'cleanup is available in the play using: {{cleanup}}'
    - debug:
          msg: 'cleanup is also available globally using: {{hostvars["localhost"]["cleanup"]}}'

- name: run the cleanup yaml file
  import_playbook: cleanup.yml
  when: hostvars["localhost"]["cleanup"] == True
```

Comment: Thank you it is working fine. A small doubt in when condition. Can you please tell the reason for comparing the variable with True instead of yes. How does Ansible know that True is for yes?

Comment: set_fact automatically converts boolean strings into booleans.